# default socket timeout [XAMPP HTTPS]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, sockets, https

I am using xampp (php version 5.25) and using https. I'm executing some scripts using rest api which takes more than 60 seconds to execute but i keep on getting this error
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

I have tried setting default socket timeout in my script but with no success.

```
 ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 120);
```

I also uncommented

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so //http.conf apache file
```

and created .htaccess with

```
php_value default_socket_timeout 9000
```

But still, error message says maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded.
I also checked Master and Local values of "default_socket_timeout" from phpinfo(), they say its 60.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this at the top of your PHP script.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

If you have several php files that will take more than the default 30 seconds, you may want to change it globally via php.ini file by editing this line:

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time=30
```